# Объясните код и раскройте функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю Phyton по книге A Byte Of Phyton и не понимаю "Переменные числа параметров" Можете просто раскрыть функцию, то есть объяснить почему пишется то или иное слово или функция

Сама функция:

```
def total(a=5, *numbers, **phonebook):
    print('a', a)

    #проход по всем элементам кортежа
    for single_item in numbers:
        print('single_item', single_item)

    #проход по всем элементам словаря
    for first_part, second_part in phonebook.items():
        print(first_part,second_part)

print(total(10,1,2,3,Jack=1123,John=2231,Inge=1560))
```

Comment: Ну это вам надо что-нибудь почитать, какую-то документацию по Python. Тут просто обычные циклы по элементам кортежа и словаря. Вам вообще все слова непонятны?

Comment: Очевидно, что значений функций знаю def print и т.д, но не понимаю сам алгоритм. Как я это вижу: Создаем функцию с помощью def называем ее total и вписываем в нее значения a=5, *numbers, **phonebook - понимаю, что * ставим чтобы дать numbers и phonebook неограниченное число параметров, но не понимаю зачем это делать. Далее for (для) single_item in (в) numbers и print ('single_item', single_item) - для чего это нужно было писать, не понимаю, то же самое и со следующей функцией. В конце print (total (суммарно) - тоже не особо понимаю зачем это здесь и рандомные цифры.

Comment: В конце же вызывается эта функция, которую вы вначале определяете. И вызывается с переменным числом параметров. С любым. И вот эти хитрые конструкции *number, **phonebook позволяют принять это произвольное число параметров.

Answer (score 1):

В Python определения и вызовы функций имеют нюансы,
которые вы должны прочувствовать на данном примере.

Я добавил несколько вызовов функции с разными аргументами,
запустите пример и посмотрите как они (аргументами) принимаются в функции.
Обратите внимание на параметр `a`, который имеет значение по умолчанию `5` (a=5)

В программировании функции могут не только возвращать данные,
но также принимать их, что реализуется с помощью так называемых параметров,
которые указываются в скобках в заголовке функции. Количество параметров может быть любым.

Параметры представляют собой локальные переменные,
которым присваиваются значения в момент вызова функции.
Конкретные значения, которые передаются в функцию при ее вызове, будем называть аргументами.

```
def total(a=5, *numbers, **phonebook):
    print(f'\ndef total: \n\ta={a}, \n\tnumbers   -> {numbers} \n\tphonebook -> {phonebook}')

    print('\n# проход по всем элементам кортежа')
    for single_item in numbers:
        print('single_item: ', single_item)

    print('\n# проход по всем элементам словаря')
    for first_part, second_part in phonebook.items():
        print(first_part, second_part)
        #      ключ         значение

# вызов функции 1 `total`
total( 10,  1, 2, 3, Jack=1123, John=2231, Inge=1560 )
#      a    numbers  |<------- phonebook --------->|

# вызов функции 2 `total`
total()

# вызов функции 3 `total`
total('Hello', 'World', Привет='JustLearn')
```